# C++: question about move constructor/assignment using Stroustrup example

Tags: c++, c++11, move-constructor, move-assignment-operator

I understand how an rvalue would invoke the move constructor and move assignment operator, however I'm confused why the same code in  Stroustrup's example below for move assignment isn't used for the move constructor.  This is from C++ 4th Ed. Page 379 revised errata.

As all the objects in the class are copied in the move constructor, why can't the move constructor simply swap pointers of the object like the move assignment operator?

Perhaps I'm missing something and appreciate your guidance!

```
template<typename T, typename A = allocator<T>>
struct vector_base {                    // memory structure for vector
    A alloc;        // allocator
    T* elem;        // start of allocation
    T* space;       // end of element sequence, start of space allocated for possible expansion
    T* last;        // end of allocated space

    vector_base(const A& a, typename A::size_type n, typename A::size_type m =0)
        : alloc{a}, elem{alloc.allocate(n+m)}, space{elem+n}, last{elem+n+m} { }
    ~vector_base() { alloc.deallocate(elem,last-elem); }

    vector_base(const vector_base&) = delete;           // no copy operations
    vector_base& operator=(const vector_base&) = delete;

    vector_base(vector_base&&);                     // move operations
    vector_base& operator=(vector_base&&);
};
template<typename T, typename A>
vector_base<T,A>::vector_base(vector_base&& a)
    : alloc{a.alloc},
    elem{a.elem},
    space{a.space},
    last{a.last}    
{
    a.elem = a.space = a.last = nullptr;    // no longer owns any memory
}

template<typename T, typename A>
vector_base<T,A>& vector_base<T,A>::operator=(vector_base&& a)
{
    swap(*this,a);
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: In the constructor, `elem` et al are uninitialized. You don't want to leave `a` holding random garbage.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, can you elaborate? Wouldn't `elem` et al all be initialized already in the rvalue passed to the move constructor?  That rvalue would have been constructed with the standard constructor?

Comment: `a.elem` is initialized. `this->elem` is not. If you swap at this point, then `this->elem` would be initialized, and `a.elem` would be garbage. Then `a`'s destructor would likely crash.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik whats wrong with leaves a.elem as uninitialized, its an rvalue correct?  Therefore will not be used again because it's not an lvalue?  Maybe my understanding of rvalue and move is incorrect?

Comment: It will be destroyed. It must be left in a state where its destructor can run successfully.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So the move constructor cannot do a swap because it's members are uninitialized and the destructor will not work correctly on the passed rvalue.  Therefore the move constructor must copy each element one by one and set the rvalue's members to null, so the rvalue destructor will work.  The move assignment can do the swap with the rvalue, because the when the rvalue destructor is invoked the data will be valid (and be the data from the regular constructor of the potential lvalue).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Correct. Besides, the move assignment needs to ensure that the old data held by `*this` is destroyed and not leaked. Handing it over to `a` achieves this goal, as `a` is expected to be destroyed shortly afterwards. (Move constructor doesn't have any old data to deal with). Now, move constructor doesn't **have** to use `swap` - it could explicitly destroy the current data, copy over new data from `a`, and set `a`'s members to null. `swap` is just a shortcut.

Comment: On your above comment, I think you meant move assignment and wrote move constructor by accident. "Now, move constructor doesn't have to use swap" -> "Now, move assignment doesn't have to use swap.  Correct/

Comment: Yes, correct. I meant "move assignment operator doesn't have to use `swap`".

Comment: Does the swap function `swap(*this,a)` ultimately call the copy assignment or copy constructor for vector_base<>?  I see the code is `template <class T> void swap ( T& a, T& b ) { T c(a); a=b; b=c; }`.  If it does I'm confused how it works because both operations are removed by being set to `delete`.  Thanks again

Comment: I haven't read the book, but I presume there's a specialization of `std::swap`, or an overload outside `std` namespace, taking `vector_base`. The swap trick doesn't make sense otherwise, as the stock `std::swap` would invoke copy or move constructors, and be inefficient at best and cause an infinite recursion at worst.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The move constructor cannot do a swap because it's members are uninitialized and the destructor will not work correctly on the passed rvalue. Therefore the move constructor must copy each element one by one and set the rvalue's members to null, so the rvalue destructor will work. The move assignment can do the swap with the rvalue, because the when the rvalue destructor is invoked the data will be valid (and be the data from the regular constructor of the potential lvalue).